# Как залить текст в ImageMagick нужным цветом

Tags: imagemagick

Нужно залить текст нужным цветом в данной картинки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

с помощью ImageMagick

Делаю это таким способом:

```
convert -background transparent temp1.png \( -clone 0 -fill '#3e312b' -colorize 90% -draw "color 0,0 reset" \) -compose atop -composite temp.png
```

Но в результате получается только задать цвет внешний обводки. Если в `-background` указать не `transparent`, а нужный цвет заливки `'#3e312b'`, то заливается все прямоугольником

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно выйти так (залил в gimp для образца, как должно быть)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Знаю, что `-fill '#3e312b'` прекрасно применяется для заливки внешнего текста нужным цветом, если текст не прозрачный и понимаю, что обводка в данном случае делается корректно. Т.к. внутри буквы `transparent`. Но нужно залить именно в таком формате, не меняя внутренний `transparent` в исходном варианте.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде бы есть отдельные параметры для цвета текста (fillcolor) и цвета фона (bgcolor).

Из ответа на en.SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10750352/2790048. Выделил отступами нужные строки.

```
$width = '600';
$height = '200';
$im = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFont('arial.ttf');
$draw->setFontSize( 96 );

$fillcolor = new ImagickPixel( "white" );

$draw->setFillColor( $fillcolor );
$draw->setGravity( Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER );

$bgcolor = new ImagickPixel( "black" );

$text = 'Rubblewebs';
$im->newImage($width, $height, $bgcolor );
$im->annotateImage($draw, 0, 0, 0, $text);
$im->setImageFormat("png");
$im->writeImage( 'text.png' );
```